# How to make elastic increase a counter on every update?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I want to create a `(url,visits)` index on `elasticsearch` which will hold the number of visits a particular url every time I call function `myfunction`. How can I do that? So far, I have managed to create the insertion but I am unable to increase the counter.

```
def myfunction():
    a = elasticsearch.index(index='test_index_1' , doc_type='test_doc_type' , id="url" , body={'data' : {'visits' : 1} , 'doc_as_upsert' : True})
    app.logger.info(a)
    b = elasticsearch.update(index='test_index_1' , doc_type='test_doc_type' , id="url" , body={
        'script' : 'ctx._source.data.visits += visit',
        'params' : {
            'visit' : 1
        }
    })
    app.logger.info(b)
```

Comment: There is a proprty called `version` which is maintained for every document.It gets updated for every updation. You can use that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the upsert parameter. The document with `id:url` should be created with a default `visits:1` if it doesn’t already exist:

```
POST /test_index_1/test_doc_type/{id}/_update
{
   "script" : "ctx._source.visits+=1",
   "upsert": {
       "visits": 1
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how can I translate this to `elasticsearch-py`? this doesn't look like to work: `b = elasticsearch.update(index='test_index_1' , doc_type='test_doc_type' , id="url" , body={
  'script' : 'ctx._source.data.visits+=1',
  'upsert' : {
   "visits": 1
  }
 })`

Comment: I haven't used elasticsearch-py but can you share the issue you are facing in converting this to elasticsearch-py syntax?